# Conditional write using cloud dataflow and pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use cloud dataflow's Python API to write a simple program that accepts input from a pubsub publisher, checks the input for a condition, and then outputs data to a topic. I have gotten the program written to where it is accepting and transforming input, as well as publishing data to a topic. My problem is that I want to only publish to the topic if a condition is true. For instance, if a keyword is present in the json data, then I want to publish a message to the pubsub topic, but not publish a message when the keyword doesn't exist. I have tried adding a global boolean flag that becomes true when a keyword is found, and wrapped it around these lines:

```
output = (lines
          | 'format' >> beam.Map(format_result)
          | 'encode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8')).with_output_types(six.binary_type))
output | beam.io.WriteStringsToPubSub(self.output_topic)
```

That did not work. And I'm running out of ideas. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ParDo that yields elements only when the condition is satisfied. For example, consider the following message structure where the `publish` field indicates whether the processed message should be outputted by the ParDo or not:

```
{"publish":"true","body":"This message should be published"}
{"publish":"false","body":"This message should *NOT* be published"}
```

We will only yield the values when `publish` is set to `true`:

```py
class FilterFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        if (element['publish'] == 'true'):
          yield element['body']
```

and the main pipeline code:

```py
lines = p | 'Read messages' >> beam.io.ReadStringsFromPubSub(topic=known_args.input)
jsons = lines | 'Load into JSON' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
filtered = jsons | 'Filter messages' >> beam.ParDo(FilterFn())
filtered | 'Publish messages' >> beam.io.WriteStringsToPubSub(topic=known_args.output)
```

Pulling the messages from the output subscription will return only one message:

> This message should be published